# How to debug PhantomJS errors?

Tags: phantomjs

While running `phantomjs --debug=true "testfile"` I am getting:

```
Recorded 45 JS errors during test run
```

I am seeing all network errors. Even after resolving all the network errors I am still getting same no. of errors.
Please help me how to find other errors.

Comment: The message is most likely generated by your script, so you should investigate that.

Comment: @Vaviloff: thanks for the reply. SO the problem is that I am unable to investigate what is the error because except network error its not showing other errors.

Comment: You should look into how and why the script decides there are network errors.